# How to set width and height of svg in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am currently having an issue when setting width and height of a svg object in fabricjs.  I tried setting it like this

```
   svg.width = 100;
   svg.height = 100;
```

But I am not getting the result I expected. It just crops the svg instead of scaling it. So, how can I set its width and height properly?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [**`scaleToWidth()`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#scaleToWidth) and [**`scaleToHeight()`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#scaleToHeight) method to properly set SVG object­*'s* width and height respectively.

**:-: working example :-:**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric-canvas');
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/1029/files/Freesample.svg?5153', function(objects, options) {
   var svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
   svg.left = 50;
   svg.top = 50;
   svg.scaleToWidth(100);
   svg.scaleToHeight(100);
   canvas.add(svg);
   canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.13/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="fabric-canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ah, Thanks. Works perfectly!

Comment: Please use stable __placeholder__ images to avoid broken images as well as undesired traffic to sites. For example use https://placeholder.pics/

Comment: What is the `svg.left = 50` and `svg.right = 50` for?